# Mínimo de bits necessário para representar um número natural

Tags: javascript, inteiros, bit

Qual a maneira mais performática de descobrir o número mínimo de bits necessário para representar um número natural (i.e. sem sinal), em JavaScript? Há um meio de fazer sem usar loops?

O código abaixo por exemplo funciona para todo inteiro entre `0` e `2^30 - 1` (loop infinito se ele for maior que isso):

```
var x = 9001;
var bits = 1;
while ( x >= (1 << bits) )
    bits++;
```

E esse funciona até `2^53` (o maior inteiro representável garantidamente sem perda de precisão) e um tanto além:

```
var x = 9001;
var bits = 1;
var limite = 2;
while ( x >= limite ) {
    bits++;
    limite *= 2;
}
```

Mas ambos usam loops, basicamente perguntando: cabe em 1 bit? cabe em 2 bits? cabe em 3 bits? etc. Fiquei curioso em saber se há uma maneira melhor de fazer isso.

**Nota:** estou interessado apenas em *saber* quantos bits são necessários, não em realmente fazer essa representação de fato. Mesmo porque JavaScript não usa `int`, `long`, `unsigned int`, etc - e sim `double` pra tudo... (e [quando usa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators), não expõe para o programador)

Comment: Eu soaria ainda mais estúpido do que pareço se eu perguntasse o porquê dessa pergunta?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto Originalmente, eu queria armazenar uma máscara de bits e um identificador único em um único `Number`. Pra isso eu precisava saber se o identificador (variável) "cabe" no espaço que sobra além da máscara (fixa). Enquanto escrevia a pergunta, percebi que dizer se cabe ou não é fácil - basta eu subtrair dos `53` bits disponíveis o tamanho da máscara, e ver se o identificador está entre zero e o maior número que cabe nesse espaço. Mas continuei curioso pra saber se há um meio de determinar o menor número de bits necessário, dado um número, então submeti a pergunta assim mesmo.

Comment: No caso geral, calcular o logaritmo de um número - mesmo aproximado - é complicado, mas no binário fica fácil: é só contar os bits à direita do último bit setado (inclusive). Mas será que dá pra fazer isso com uma operação simples? Eu não sei, e pensei que talvez alguém conhecesse um meio...

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, o aspecto matemático:

Um número positivo e inteiro **n** tem **b** bits quando 2<sup>**b**-1</sup> < **n** < 2<sup>**b**</sup>-1.

Isso significa dizer que, enquanto meu inteiro não ultrapassar o valor de uma dada potência de 2, a quantidade de bits necessária para expressar esse inteiro é a base dessa potência menos um. Exemplos:

```
Decimal   Próxima potência de 2  Bitmap      Bits necessários
511       512  (2^10)            111111111   9
967       1024 (2^11)            1111000111  10
```

Logo, para calcular quantos bits **b** são necessários para expressar um número **n**, podemos usar logaritmos. Assim:

**b**<sub>inteiro</sub> = int(log<sup>2</sup>(**n**)) + 1

Essa fórmula pode ser dividida em três partes:

- log<sup>2</sup>(**n**) significa o logaritmo em base 2 de N, que é o expoente ao qual 2 é elevado para chegar a N. Javascript não suporta cálculos de logaritmo em base diferente de 10, então precisamos dividir `Math.log(n)` por `Math.log(2)`.
- Int(**x**) é a parte inteira de **x**. Em Javascript, a função equivalente é `Math.floor()`.
- **+1** joga o expoente para a próxima potência de 2, para compensar pela última posição de seu número em expressão binária.

Uma maneira de expressar esta  fórmula em `JavaScript` seria:

```
function numBits(numero)
{
    return Math.floor( Math.log(numero) / Math.log(2) ) + 1;
}
```

[Eu preparei um JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42B3x/1/) onde você pode testar a performance de cada método. Assuma métodos 1 e 2 como os na sua pergunta original, e 3 como sendo o desta resposta.

Meus resultados para um ciclo de 1 a 50.000.000 foram:

```
Método 1: 3244 ms
Método 2: 2103 ms
Método 3:  181 ms
(Browser: Google Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125)

Método 1: 1564 ms
Método 2: 2434 ms
Método 3: 2518 ms
(Browser: Internet Explorer 11)
```

Fontes:

- [Number of Bits in a Decimal Integer - Exploring Binary](http://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-bits-in-a-decimal-integer/)
- [How can I specify the base for Math.log() in JavaScript? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019278/how-can-i-specify-the-base-for-math-log-in-javascript)
- [javascript - Number of bits to represent a number - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081271/number-of-bits-to-represent-a-number)

Comment: Há que notar que esta solução (sem ciclos) não é necessariamente mais performant que uma solução com ciclos: isso vai depender de como o interpretador de JS vai optimizar os ciclos e de como as funções do `Math` estão implementadas.

Comment: @MiguelVentura Pois é, também pensei nisso. Logaritmo me passou pela cabeça, mas descartei logo pensando na performance. [De fato, ele é mais lento](http://jsperf.com/contagem-de-bits) (para números relativamente pequenos, pelo menos). De todo modo, +1 pelo aspecto matemático.

Comment: A propósito, eu achei que a solução com ciclos seria melhor para números pequenos, e a com logaritmo melhor para números grandes, [mas não é o que observei](http://jsperf.com/contagem-de-bits/2). Provavelmente, o cálculo do logaritmo não é mesmo feito em tempo constante...

Comment: P.S. De fato, no Chrome é mais rápido para números muito grandes! Provavelmente o algoritmo deles de log é melhor

Comment: Pois é - curioso, não? Fiquei com vontade de testar em outros browsers...